# Type mismatch found while using Generic in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I am converting [**this code**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173504/generic-adapter-with-search-and-sort-functionality) to kotlin

where

```
abstract class BaseModel(){
}
```

**BaseViewHolder**

```
abstract class BaseViewHolder<T : BaseModel>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    abstract fun bindData(data: T)
}
```

**BaseAdapter**

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<T:BaseModel, U : BaseViewHolder<*>>(var items: List<T>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<U>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): U {
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: U, pos: Int) {
        holder.bindData(items.get(pos))
    }
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder` the method `holder.bindData` gives an error **type mismatch require Nothing found T**

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `BaseAdapter<T:BaseModel, U : BaseViewHolder<T>>` try this

Comment: Thanks ClickSol Apps I understand my mistake!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `BaseViewHolder<*>` from `*` to `T`

Just like this

```
...BaseAdapter<T:BaseModel, U : BaseViewHolder<T>>...
```